# Галочки не убираются корректно

Tags: java, android

Есть поле дни.

В нём *список* со днями(пн-вс), напротив каждого дня стоит поле для галочек.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Убираем любое кол-во галочек и нажимаем "ОК"
Возвращаемся назад к полю, после чего опять переходим в список со днями.
Ставим галочки там, где они убраны и нажимаем "Отмена".
Возвращаемся к полю, опять  открываем список с днями.
Галочки остались выбранными.

Код во фрагменте:

```
  @OnClick(R.id.day_dialog)
public void statusClick(View view) {
    new DialogAutorepublish(getActivity(), infoAutoUpdate, getResources().getString(R.string.Days), new DialogAutorepublish.IDialogActions() {

        @Override
        public void addClick(List<model.ads.autoupdate.otherInfo> list) {
            String changeDay = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                if (list.get(i).isSelectedl() == true) {
                    changeDay = new StringBuilder().append(changeDay + ",").append(list.get(i).getDayShort()).toString();
                }
            }
            setView(changeDay);

        }

        @Override
        public void cancelClick() {

        }
    }).show();
}
```

Отрывок кода `DialogAutorepublish`:

```
@OnClick(R.id.cancelbtn)
void cancelClick() {
    dismiss();
    for (int i = 0; i < tempList.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < daySelected.size(); j++) {
            if (daySelected.get(j).getPosition() == tempList.get(i)) {
                daySelected.get(j).setSelectedl(true);
            }
        }

    }
    listener.cancelClick();
}

@OnClick(R.id.okbtn)
void addNewsClick() {
    dismiss();
    listener.addClick(daySelected);
}
```

Comment: извините, но ваше описание совершенно непонятно

Comment: больше кода с коментами к нему.